# Combining a translate and alpha animation causes a flicker at the beginning of the animation in Android

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm setting up a simple animation that fades an imageview in while shifting it up on the screen.

The fadein occurs fine, but when I add the translate animation in XML the full-opacity image flickers onscreen at the original position.

Here is the code of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillBefore="true">
    <set android:duration="1500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true">
        <alpha
            android:duration="1200"
            android:fromAlpha="0"
            android:toAlpha="0.8"/>
        <alpha android:duration="300"
            android:startOffset="1200"
            android:fromAlpha="0.8"
            android:toAlpha="0.95"/>
        <translate
            android:toXDelta="0"
            android:toYDelta="-400.0"
            />
    </set>
    <set android:duration="300" android:startOffset="1500">
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.95"
            android:toAlpha="0.7"/>
    </set>
    <set android:duration="600" android:startOffset="1800">
    </set>
    <set android:duration="600" android:startOffset="2400">
        <alpha android:toAlpha="0"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

And here is how I call it:

```
 public void animateVote(View view) {
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_streem_capture_wrapper);
    Animation voteAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.vote_1);
    layout.addView(view);
    view.startAnimation(voteAnimation);

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a really weird animation file. Why are you adding empty <set/> tags?

Comment: It's a placeholder for other animation elements. I'm planning on adding the elements there later. Is that distracting?

Comment: By the way one solution here is to flatten the XML by getting rid of the sets. But I liked the visualization of having sets embody periods of time during which simultaenous animations happen. Help would be appreciated to keep that setup while getting rid of the flicker.